# after login unable to stay on current page

Tags: angular-ui-router

i am using $stateChangeStart instead of routechangestart , the problem i am facing is that after login whenever i refresh page i get redirected to home page,here is my code?

```
$rootScope.$on(‘$stateChangeStart’, function (event,next, toState, toParams,fromState, fromParams, options) {

if(next.name === “product.login” && $rootScope.authenticated) {
event.preventDefault();
} else if (next.name && next.data.requireLogin && !$rootScope.authenticated )     {
event.preventDefault();
$rootScope.$broadcast(“event:auth-loginRequired”, {});
}
 else if (next.name && !AuthSharedService.isAuthorized(next.data.requiredRole)) {
event.preventDefault();
$rootScope.$broadcast(“event:auth-forbidden”, {});
}
}
);

$rootScope.$on(‘event:auth-loginConfirmed’, function (next,tostate,toparams, data,event) 
{
 console.log(‘login confirmed start for ‘ + tostate);

$rootScope.loadingAccount = false;

var nextLocation = ($rootScope.$state.current.name?  $rootScope.$state.current.name : “frontProduct.productgrid”);
Session.create(tostate);
$rootScope.account = Session;
$rootScope.authenticated = true;
$state.go(nextLocation);

});
```

i just want to stay on current page.help me!

Answer (score 1):

Hope you doing well

you have to also specify if user is not authenticated then where user redirect

```
if (!$rootScope.userloggedIn && !$rootScope.authenticate) {
                    $state.go("login");
                    event.preventDefault();
}
else{
     $state.go("home");
}
```

look like this.
Hope this help you.

Comment: thanks for your reply mayur, but this doesnt help me as in my application user can go to any page which doesnt require authentication.so i didnt bothered to mention this.

Comment: then why are you check user is authenticated or not ?

Comment: my problem is redirecting user after login not before login. i am unable to hold user on current page and if user wants to go to page where authentication is required my login page automatically popups i had already used this condition.

Answer (score 0):

found answer,

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event,next, toState, toParams,fromState, fromParams) {


     if(next.name === "product.login" && $rootScope.authenticated) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (next.name && next.data.requireLogin && !$rootScope.authenticated ) {
         if(next.name!="product.login"&&next.name!=""){$window.localStorage.setItem('url',next.name);}
      event.preventDefault();
        $rootScope.$broadcast("event:auth-loginRequired", {});
    }
    else if (next.name && !AuthSharedService.isAuthorized(next.data.requiredRole)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $rootScope.$broadcast("event:auth-forbidden", {});
    }
}
        );


$rootScope.$on('event:auth-loginConfirmed', function (next,tostate,toparams, data,event,$stateProvider) {
    console.log('login confirmed start for ' + tostate);


    $rootScope.loadingAccount = false;

$rootScope.$state.current.name : "frontProduct.productgrid");
   Session.create(tostate);
        $rootScope.account = Session;
        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
$state.go($window.localStorage.getItem('url'));
$window.localStorage.remove('url');



});
```

i just want to know is this a correct way.